# Books on limiting properties of matrices with growing size

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, soft-question, st.statistics

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267257/books-on-limiting-properties-of-matrices-with-growing-size) has been posted on Math-Se previously.

I am studying asymptotic   properties of the [Projection Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267257/books-on-limiting-properties-of-matrices-with-growing-size)
$$
H_n=X'(X'X)^{-1}X
$$
By the Gerschgorin disc theorem, the bounds on the eigenvalues of $H_n$
\begin{align*}
 \min_i(h_{ii}-\sum^{n}_{j\neq i} |h_{ij}|)\leq \rho(H_n)\leq \max_i(h_{ii}+\sum^{n}_{j\neq i} |h_{ij}|)
 \end{align*}
Since $h_{ij}^2\leq h_{ii}h_{jj}$, (see Chatterjee and Hadi, 1998),  if the matrix satisfies
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \max_i h_{ii}=0\implies   \rho(H_{\infty})=0
 \end{align*}
Is the above reasoning valid? If someone could provide me with the books on sequence of growing matrices and the tools to compute their limiting properties that would be great.I have seen [papers](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82817688.pdf) like this in the internet which is very relevant but could not find a textbook on this topic.

Comment: Consider the orthogonal projection $H_n$ onto the $n$-dimensional all-ones vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$. Then each diagonal entry of $H_n$ is $1/n$, which tends to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, each $H_n$ has an eigenvalue of $1$. Is that a contradiction to what you're asking?

Comment: This bugs me as well. I think it depends on what $H_\infty$ is.

Comment: I'm assuming $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix with typically $n\gg p,$ so $H_n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $H_g$ just means the number of rows is $g$ rather than $n.$ If I understand you correctly then, $H_g$ is a $g\times g$ matrix. But $\le p$ of its eigenvalues are $1$ and the others are $0,$ and it seems that that's all you can say about "bounds" on its eigenvalues. And that (and other things) make me think I haven't yet properly understood you.

Comment: To speak of $\text{“} \lim\limits_{n\,\to\,\infty} \text{”}$ you would need an infinite sequence of matrices $X_n \in \mathbb R^{n\times p}$ (where $p$ stays fixed as $n$ grows? or not?) and it's not clear whether you go from $n$ to $n+1$ simply by adding another row to the matrix $X_n$ while the rows that were already there stay put. And how are the values of the new rows determined? In typical applications you have the elements in each row being either independent observations from some probability distribution with finite variance, with$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$different distributions for different rows, or else the new values are chosen by the designer of an experiment, perhaps based on some optimality criterion. So the question is: what can you tell us about the new rows of $X$ that are added as $n$ grows? $\qquad$

Comment: If the tall skinny matrix $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ has linearly independent columns then $X'X\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$ is invertible; otherwise it's not. If it's invertible, then exactly $p$ of the eigenvalues of $H\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are $1$ and the other $n-p$ eigenvalues are $0. \qquad$

Comment: Dumb typo: I meant "the elements in each COLUMN being [...] independent observations from some probability distribution with finite variance". And with different probabity distributions for different COLUMNS.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I am interested from a conditional prospective where $X_n$ are considered fixed and known. Each $X_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ but $p$ and $n$ could grow to infinity. I would be interested in the case where $p$ and $n$ grow at the same rate but $p<n$.